# How to populate room database with String resources

Tags: database, android-room

I want to populate my `Room` database with `String resource` but I can't.

I have this:

`userDao.insertUser(User(getString(R.string.name)))`

but `getString()` it's not working here.

I need to pass `context` like this:

`context.getString(R.string.name)))` but I don't know how to pass `context` here.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have populated it with hardcoded Strings first.
When the user starts the App for the first time I edit the prepopulated Strings  to the right translation. By just passing the right Strings with the Dao to the database.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, it is bad practices to access `context` in @Dao classes.

You might want to consider setting the `getString(R.string.name)` into String variable first, assign it into `User` object, then only you add it to roomdb.

```
--- In View ---
val name = context.getString(R.string.name)
val user = User(name, xxx, xxx)

--- In Dao ---
userDao.insertUser(user)
```